# How to use functions correctly with arguments in Coffee script

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

I'm pretty new to coffee script, and could use a hand! I'm having trouble understanding how functions take/use arguments. For example, this is what I'm wanting to do. Pass any div I want in the `track` argument, which the `initiate` function should check if is present, and if so pass it to the `trackMe` function, so it can manipulate some html. Where am I going wrong?

Index:

```
<script>
Range.initiate(30000, {track: $('.div-test')});
</script>
```

Coffeescript:

```
window.Range =

  trackMe: (div) ->
    div.html("<p>Submitted</p>")

  initiate: (time, track) ->
    sayhello = true
      action: =>
        esSendMe.send()
      go: time
    if track
      @trackMe(track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a hundred percent sure what you're willing to implement, focusing on Coffee though.

Prepared a little working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/grxn2pbf/1/

Basically you have a wrong indentation here:

```
sayhello = true
  action: =>
    esSendMe.send()
  go: time
```

Wrote some comments in the fiddle, including this section. If you want to instantiate an object right there you have to assign it to a variable though:

```
sayhello = true
obj =
  action: =>
    esSendMe.send()
  go: time
```

Furthermore, you're handing an object to the initiate function:

```
Range.initiate(30000, {track: $('.div-test')});
```

If you want to access the element in the function though, you need to access the attribute of your param:

```
initiate: (time, track) ->
  console.log track.track
```

Check the working example, as I said, wrote a couple of comments in there! :)

If you have any additional questions please don't hesitate to comment!

Comment: Thank you so much! :) This helped a ton.